# Setting selected values in a Listbox from the model in .net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, select, listbox

I am trying to bind my model to Multiple Select in .net MVC. This is my model

```
public class RuoloProgetto
{
    [Key]
    public int id_ruolo_prog { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Ruolo")]
    public int id_ruolo { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("id_ruolo")]
    public virtual Ruolo ruolo { get; set; }
    public int id_progetto { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("id_progetto")]
    //public virtual Progetto progetto { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Utente")]
    public string id_utente { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("id_utente")]
    public virtual IdentityUser utente { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Carico di lavoro in %")]
    [Required]
    public int percentuale { get; set; }
    public int versione { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Moduli Responsabile")]
    public int[] Choices { get; set; }
    public  virtual List<ModelRP> moduli { get; set; }
}
```

This is in my controller function that sets the values for the selectlist:

```
 List<SelectListItem> specifiche = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var specifiche2 = db.Specificha.Where(p => p.id_progetto == Progetti.id_progetto).Select(x => new { x.id_specifiche, x.desc_specifiche }).ToList();

        foreach (var item in specifiche2)
        {
            specifiche.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.id_specifiche.ToString(), Text = item.desc_specifiche });
        }
        ViewData["Specs"] = specifiche;
```

and this is in my view:

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(m => item.Choices,
     new MultiSelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Specs"], "Value", "Text",
     item.moduli.Select(fl => new SelectListItem
     {
         Text = fl.moduloutente.desc_specifiche.ToString(),
         Value = fl.moduloutente.id_specifiche.ToString(),
         Selected = item.moduli.Any(y => y.id_specifiche == fl.id_specifiche)  
     })),
     new
     {
         Selected = true,
         @Class = "js-example-basic-multiple form-control",
         Multiple = "multiple",
         @Name = "progetto.ruoloprogetto[" + index + "].Choices",
         @Id = "progetto.ruoloprogetto[" + index + "]_Choices",
         @Placeholder = "Moduli",
     })
```

The ViewData comes ok! The problem is with the selected values! When I check in immediate window item.moduli is correctly filled with the data, but nothing appears as selected in the interface!

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your binding the list box to property `Choices` so you need to set the value of `Choices` in the controller before you pass the view and then just

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => item.Choices, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Specs"], new { @class = "js-example-basic-multiple form-control" })
```

If the values of the option values are (say) 1 to 10, and `Choices` is `[2, 4]` then the second and forth options will be selected.

Note also do not need to set `Multiple = "multiple"` (thats already done by the helper), and you should not be trying to override the name attribute (other wise binding will fail on post back). In addition `Selected` and `Placeholder` are not valid attributes for `<select>`

Comment: i dont have a problem with the post, because I do get the values that were selected. My problem is only with filling the selected values. These are not in Choices but in a list item.moduli (which is the model of a table in db)

Comment: You misunderstanding how bind works - your binding to `Choices` so if its value is `null` or does not contain any values that match the value of the options, then nothing will be selected. And look at the html your generating for this If the name attribute really is `"progetto.ruoloprogetto[0].Choices"` and you binding then you have some other binding issues - are you doing something with a collection and trying to override the default behavior?

Comment: You are right, I am making a mess out of this! Need to start over. Could you suggest me the model structure I need to have in order to create a multiple select ListBox in .net? I would be so grateful! I am very new at .net, just started learning from scratch a couple months ago. Also, by the way, I am using that naming because I am creating objects on the fly and I needed to distinguish them by an index

Comment: The code I have shown above will work fine for binding to a multiple select. But you can simplify your controller code to two lines `var specifiche2 = db.Specificha.Where(p => p.id_progetto == Progetti.id_progetto); ViewData["Specs"] = new SelectList(specifiche2 , "id_specifiche", "desc_specifiche");` then set the value of `Choices` - e.g. `model.Choices = new int[] { 1, 2 }; return View(model);`

Comment: When you say you are _creating objects on the fly_ do you mean you are  using javascript/jquery. I suggest you edit your question to include the POST method.

Comment: Thank you, yes I am using jquery to create the objects on the fly. There is one last thing. I need to get both the value and text of my choice so I can display the text and get the value when its selected. how should I declare the Choices in my model?

Comment: If you are dynamically trying to create multiple selects using jquery then you are going to have problems binding like this (I suggest you post your code). The typeof Choices should match the typeof `id_specifiche` (if `id_specifiche` is `int`, then it should be `int[]`)